# Need to substitute \x0d\x0a to \x2c\x0d\x0a in a file

Tags: awk, hex

I need to substitute `\x0d\x0a` to `\x2c\x0d\x0a` in a file

The following does not do anything:

```
awk '{if NR> 1 {gsub(/\x0D\x0A/,"\x2C\x0D\x0A"); print}}' test.csv > testfixed.csv
```

```
$ xxd test.csv
00000e0: 350d 0a45 4941 2d39 3330 2c44 6169 6c79  5..EIA-930,Daily
00000f0: 2c4e 5949 532c 2c55 5443 302c 3030 3132  ,NYIS,,UTC0,0012
```

Comment: do simple text substitution.  Also your file has lowercase 0d 0a.

Comment: Have a look at the [awk tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) for help with your syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to make a substitution of the hex string `\x0D\x0A` which is nothing more than `CRLF` or `\r\n`.

Since [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) by default splits its records on the <newline> character (which is `LF`), you actually never have to try to match your <newline> character `\n` (or `\x0a`). So all you need to do is substitute `\r` into `,\r` (`0x2c` is the hex value of `,`). So this should do the trick:

```
awk '(NR>1){sub("\r$",",\r"); print}' file
```

**So why was your script failing?**

As mentioned before, [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) works in records and the default record separator is the <newline> character. This means that the <newline> character, also written as `\n` and having hexadecimal value `\x0a`, is never part of the record `$0`. Also, the print statement automatically adds its record output separator `ORS` after the record. By default this is again the <newline> character. So you did not have to try to substitute that. All you had to do was:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {sub(/\x0D$/,"\x2C\x0D"); print}' test.csv > testfixed.csv
```

**So is it possible to substitute by means of its hexacedimal values?**

Yes, clearly it is!

```
echo -n "Hello World" | awk 'sub(/\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64/,"\x43\x6f\x77")'
```

**But how can I change <newline>?**

You can just redefine the output record separator `ORS`:

```
awk -v ORS="whatever" '1'
```

Also, using GNU awk, you can follow [glenn jackman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52954118/8344060).

---

Very much related: [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The newline `\n` or `\x0A` will not appear in each record because by default it is the record separator.

I would do this: define the *input* and *output* record separators to be `\r\n` and then for line number > 1, append a comma to the record:

```
$ printf "a\r\nb\r\nc\r\n" >| file

$ hexdump -C file
00000000  61 0d 0a 62 0d 0a 63 0d  0a                       |a..b..c..|
00000009

$ awk 'BEGIN {RS = ORS = "\r\n"} NR > 1 {$0 = $0 ","} 1' file | hexdump -C
00000000  61 0d 0a 62 2c 0d 0a 63  2c 0d 0a                 |a..b,..c,..|
0000000b
```

Comment: Ah yes, requires GNU awk for multi-character RS variable